# Instalaltion succeeded, but the software is not there

Tags: windows-installer

We provide our software in the msi format. While we have several hundred users who have been able to install it, we have a few who claim that the installer finishes successfully, but the software is not there. they even provided an installation log which clearly says "Installation completed successfully.", but the folder where software should have been installed is missing.

Any ideas what might go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[How to enable Windows Installer logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300)

[How to Interpret Windows Installer Logs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx)